# Axios refresh token issue

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, react-typescript

I'm using React.useEffect() to retrieve the users list.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
dispatch(UsersActions.creators.fetchingUsersAction());
UsersApi.methods.getUsers().then(
  (res) => {
    dispatch(UsersActions.creators.fetchUsersSuccessAction(res.data));
  },
  (e) => {
    dispatch(UsersActions.creators.fetchUsersErrorAction());
  }
);
}, [dispatch]);
```

On this example, fetchingUsersAction is used to set "loading" to true, and fetchUsersErrorAction to false. This works fine, except when the request fails due to token expiration.

```
ApiClient.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    return response;
  },
  function (error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;

      const refresh = JSON.stringify({
        refreshToken: localStorage.getItem("refresh"),
      });
      AuthenticationApi.methods.refresh(refresh).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.accessToken) {
          localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.accessToken);
        }
        ApiClient.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
          "Bearer " + res.data.accessToken;
        originalRequest.headers["Authorization"] =
          "Bearer " + res.data.accessToken;
        return ApiClient(originalRequest);
      });
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

This is sending a request to generate a new token and the previous request, but since the first request failed, the useEffect is going to the error section, making the "loading" false and showing the users list based on the previous state. What is the best way to deal with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: In case of an error, save the error message in the state and show the error message instead of user list.

Comment: @Yousaf Yes, I can do that. But since I am making a second request, I was wondering if there is any way I can make it "wait" for the response of the second request, instead of going into the fetchUsersErrorAction.

Comment: Do you want the requests to happen at the same time or one after the other?

Comment: @Yousaf, right now, if the first request fails due to 401 (Token expiration), the interceptors is sending a refresh request and repeating the original request. My goal is to "wait" for the response of the second request. Since the "fetchingUsersAction" is the one that sets the "loading" to true, this is not changing on the second request, failing to show the result of the second request.

Comment: Instead of using interceptors, if the first request fails, in the error-handling callback function, check if the error is related to token expiration. If that's the case, start another request instead of dispatching `fetchUsersErrorAction`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an Async fucntion inside useEffect hook and use await to wait for the response, then call the function. Here is one example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getRoles = async () => {
      await authService.roles().then((res) => {
        //Do your stuff.
        console.log(res);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(`'Catching the error: '${error}`);
      });
    };
    //Call the recent created function.
    getRoles();
  }, []);
```

Your interceptor looks good to me.